# print("string1" or "string2" in string) does not give Boolean result

Tags: python, python-3.x

why does `print("Lorem" and "aliqua" in string )`  Gives True. A Boolean,

But `print("Lorem" or "aliqua" in string )` Gives 'Lorem'. A String

```
string = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua"

print("Lorem" and "aliqua" in string )
>>> True

print("Lorem" or "aliqua" in string )
>>> Lorem
```

Comment: You are dangerously close to the error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-for-equality-against-a-single-value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
print("Lorem" in string and "aliqua" in string )
```

And

```
print("Lorem" in string or "aliqua" in string )
```

**Explanation**:
The condition in string will always be true as it checks string is non empty.

```
>>> if "harsha":
...   print("hi")
...
hi
>>> if "":
...   print("hi")
...
<<No output>>
```

Comment: `string` is not a reserved keyword, `str` is.

Comment: @Physmatik Technically `str` is not a "reserved word" but a "type name". You are free to shoot yourself in the foot and assign something to it.

Answer (score 4):

In your second example, the string "Lorem" evaluates to True and is being printed without checking if "aliqua" appears. Try searching for both.

```
any([x in string for x in ["Lorem", "aliqua"]])
>> True
```

Answer (score 4):

With boolean operations

```
x and y
x or y
```

The `and` operator returns the `y` if both `x` and `y` are both truthy. In your example `y` is `"aliqua" in string` which evaluates to `True`.

The `or` operator returns the `x` if `x` is truthy. In your example `x` is `"Lorem"`.

See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations for more details.

If the goal is to check whether `"Lorem"` or `"aliqua"` occurs in `string`, realise that `x or y in z` is not `(x or y) in z` but `x or (y in z)`. The solution is to use the `in` operator twice, e.g.

```
if (x in z) or (y in z):
    pass
```

Answer (score 2):

Logical operators, lust like arithmetic ones, have relative precedence. `*` happens before `+`; `in` happens before `and`, which happens before `or`.

In your first case, in `"Lorem" and "aliqua" in string`, evaluation happens as if parenthesis were put like this `"Lorem" and ("aliqua" in string)`. First `"aliqua" in string` evaluates to `True`, then `"Lorem" and True` evaluates to boolean `True`.

In your second case, in `"Lorem" or "aliqua" in string` evaluation order is the same: `"Lorem" or ("aliqua" in string)` -> `"Lorem" or True` -> "Lorem".

Now, however, we have to talk about one small optimization, that is used in many languages besides Python.

Logically speaking, expression `True and A` is fully equivalent to `A` (you can derive that mathematically). So, when Python sees that the first part of `and` is True (or true-ish) it just gives you the second argument. (*In Python non-zeros, non-empty arrays/dictionaries, etc., are said to be "truthy", as in they give True when passed to `bool(x)`*). Similarly with `or` — if it sees that we have something like "True-ish X and something" it just gives you back that X. Take a look:

```py
In : True and "a"
Out: 'a'

In : "a" and True
Out: True

In : True or "a"
Out: True

In : "a" or True
Out: 'a'
```

That's why in your first case `"Lorem" and True` evaluates to `True` ("Lorem" is true-ish, so Python just gives back the second argument), while in the second case `"Lorem" or True` evaluates to `"Lorem"` (Python gives back the first argument).

If you want to check whether both substrings are in a string, you can construct a longer expression

```py
"Lorem" in string and "aliqua" in strign
```

or use loops/arrays

```py
string = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit ..."
words = ["Lorem", "ipsum", "dolor"]

# `all` checks whether everything is True
print(all(word in string for word in words))
# True

# `any` checks whether at least something is True
print(any(word in string for word in words))
# True
```